# How to write a log records in tabular format I want them to display column wise in python and not using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have created logger using logging module. Now i want to print these logs in column wise but I want to print it like as one thing get complete it should go to another column.Is there any other module or function ?

I am running Python 3.7. I don't want to use pandas.

`logging.basicConfig(filename = log_file, filemode = 'a', level = logging.INFO, format =  '%(asctime)s -  %(name)s  -  %(levelname)s - %(message)s ')`

This above code is my log function. Now i want to print column wise as one loop get completed in another function.

Comment: What do you mean by "Now i want to print column wise as one loop get completed in another function"? Could you provide an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: i want my log records to be in columns. so that i can identify as one task get completed this is of another task do you understand ?